# Best way to implement a dialogue system in Game Maker Studio 2

Tags: game-development, game-maker-studio-2, game-maker-language

I am trying to implement a dialogue system for a game that I am making. I have the actual system for handling the text and input all set up. My question is asking about how you actually show the text and have it formatted properly in a certain sprite.

Answer (score 0):

The "best way" is a broad and subjective term, and it may be different for each person, but I can give you some tips regarding the question in your second sentence, to put you in the right direction:

> How to actually show the text and have it formatted properly in a certain sprite?

- Considering a dialogue box is a User Interface, you should put the code, that draws the dialog box, in the `Draw_Gui` of the object. Because that will draw stuff in front of the camera, and doesn't need to keep positions of the map in mind. Since `Draw_Gui` is in an object, you can put the dialogue box in a parent NPC, or let a seperate persistent object handle it (called an object manager)
- To format it properly within a sprite, you can use `draw_text_ext(x,y,string,sep,w)`, especially the `w` parameter will be helpful, as that allows you to let the text start on a new line if it exceeds past that width, and the `sep` parameter let you deside the space between the lines of text, to ensure the amount or lines in your dialog box will look clean.